# Write a join query with multiple tables in ruby on rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have Downloaded Document model which contains data regarding the user downloaded documents , the schema of downloaded_documents table is

```
id document_id document_type user_id
 1     444      article        1    
 2     120      judgment       2
 3     444      article        1
 4     555      rule           3
 5     555      rule           4
```

Now I want to generate report for all the downloaded documents and it users. And there is no relationship between the downloaded documents and user model, and each document_type in nothing but the each model in our application, so I want a document information also user information also. So How I write a query ?

I have written the following query:

```
DownloadedDocument.joins("JOIN users ON downloaded_documents.user_id = users.id").select("distinct on (downloaded_documents.document_id, downloaded_documents.user_id, downloaded_documents.document_type) users.email, document_type.created_at").where('created_at >=? and created_at <= ?',Date.parse(from_date), Date.parse(to_date))
```

But I am not getting the document information. I should add a one more JOIN in the above query which is nothing but `JOIN on ------downloaded_documents.document_id = -----.id` in the ---- place I need to add document type name, but for `ALL` I want all models mentioned in the document_type, so how could I write query?

My Article model schema

```
ID  title
444 first title
```

Judgment schema

```
ID  appellant_name respondent_name case_no
120   ddd               gggg         abc.123
```

Rule schema

```
ID  rule_name
555  example
```

I want a output something like this:

```
{'judgment' => [{case_no: 'abc.123',email: 'abc.example.com', dcoument_id: 120}], 'article' => [{title: 'first title', email: 'ads@example.com', document_id: 444},{title: 'first_title', email: 'fff@example.com', document_id: 444}]}
```

I want to generate a report for to list document and its users

Comment: I think it might help if you include all your table schemas with at least the important columns, sample data, and your desired results

Comment: @StephanI have added what I want

Comment: Sorry, I don't know know ruby, I only know SQL. Your table schema will help someone answer your question As far as SQL goes, if you want to join document type, you're going to have join downloaded_documents to each table of your other tables. For Article, you might do JOIN Article ON downloaded_documents.ID = Article.ID AND downloaded_documents.Type = 'Article'

Comment: for `ALL` you can write your own method

Comment: @Stephan its giving me empty result

Comment: @IvanSelivanov can you explain more

Comment: I mean, I don't think that it is possible to achieve with one query. But You can write a method, which supplements data from the query You wrote by the use of several subsequent queries.